# Transparent src so that background shows through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Do you know how to make the source image of an img tag transparent so that one can see the background image through the src image?

Say I have this html:

```
<img src="my_image.jpg" height="200" width="300" style="background:url(img/bg.jpg) repeat;" />
```

I want to somehow target the source image and set the opacity to i.ex. 0.7 .

With jQuery I could copy the src, height and width of the image and manipulate the markup into something like this:

```
<div style="background:url(img/bg/jpg) repeat; height:200px; width:300px;">
    <div style="background:url(my_image.jpg); height:200px; width:300px; opacity:0.7;"></div>
</div>
```

But does anyone have a better/simpler suggestion for how to do make this happen? Preferrably without manipulating the markup.

Comment: The image can't be made transparent independently of its background. Why would you do this?

Comment: You totally sure about that? There are ways of manipulating images with JavaScript. The reason I want to do this is to make it look like the images have a texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this with just an `<img/>`.  Try:

```
<div class="image-wrapper">
  <img src="my_image.jpg" height="200" width="300"/>
</div>

.image-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url(img/bg.jpg) repeat;
}
.image-wrapper img {
  vertical-align: top;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettwp/qundj/).

Comment: Sure, I can not do it with an img tag alone. This looks good! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping the image in a `<span></span>` and setting the background on that, then reducing the transparency of the image. It'd be less awkward than replacing the image with divs.

Comment: @MathiasMadsenStav yes, I did. You have to manipulate the markup. You're assuming that the source of an image and the image element are separate; they aren't.

Comment: What you are explaining is exactly what I provided as an example in my question. But Hey, thanks for trying :)

Comment: @MathiasMadsenStav are you trolling? No, it isn't. You move both images to backgrounds. I suggested you merely wrap the image in a span. The answer you accepted is the same as mine!

Comment: I guess I didn't quite understand exactly what you meant, an example would be a lot of help. I understand what you mean now. Sorry for the trolling, don't know what came over me.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the image in a div instead of a background, then change the z-index, then you could target it directly in the css.

Comment: I don't think you understood all of what I wrote. Added some more to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make the image partially transparent in an editor, then save as PNG (since JPG doesn't support transparency)? That'd be a lot easier than trying to code a solution.

Comment: Cause thats not efficient And then The user who uploads the photo has to have knowledge of how that would be done.

Comment: It only takes thirty seconds to write a PHP script that makes the image partially transparent...